# How to integrate linkedin in android

Tags: android

i am developing an application which post a message to the linkedin wall . Please, can any one give some sample code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: there are three answer, are you try anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a sample application for linkedin connectivity.You can download the source code the from the following link

https://github.com/srivastavavivek1987/LinkedIn-Connection-in-Android

In this sample, you get access_token for the user.

So further use [LinkedIn REST API](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api#) with access_token to post on wall.

Answer (score 1):

The site already offers Android application, consider that!

Otherwise here's some official docs: http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/

and http://developer.linkedin.com/, mostly http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/libraries-and-tools

P.S. The power of Google!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [LinkedIn API wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/) for Java.
The OAuth tokens must be your own - get them [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/).